# Python script for trasnforming ans sorting columns in ascending order, decimal cases

Tags: python, list, sorting, decimal

I wrote a script in Python removing tabs/blank spaces between two columns of strings (x,y coordinates) plus separating the columns by a comma and listing the maximum and minimum values of each column (2 values for each the x and y coordinates). E.g.:

```
100000.00    60000.00
200000.00    63000.00
300000.00    62000.00
400000.00    61000.00
500000.00    64000.00
```

became:

```
100000.00,60000.00
200000.00,63000.00
300000.00,62000.00
400000.00,61000.00
500000.00,64000.00

10000000 50000000 60000000 640000000
```

This is the code I used:

```
import string
input = open(r'C:\coordinates.txt', 'r')
output = open(r'C:\coordinates_new.txt', 'wb')
s = input.readline()
while s <> '':
    s = input.readline()
    liste = s.split()
    x = liste[0]
    y = liste[1]
    output.write(str(x) + ',' + str(y))
    output.write('\n')
    s = input.readline()
input.close()
output.close()
```

I need to change the above code to also transform the coordinates from two decimal to one decimal values and each of the two new columns to be sorted in ascending order based on the values of the x coordinate (left column).

I started by writing the following but not only is it not sorting the values, it is placing the y coordinates on the left and the x on the right. In addition I don't know how to transform the decimals since the values are strings and the only function I know is using %f and that needs floats. Any suggestions to improve the code below?

```
import string
input = open(r'C:\coordinates.txt', 'r')
output = open(r'C:\coordinates_sorted.txt', 'wb')
s = input.readline()
while s <> '':
    s = input.readline()
    liste = string.split(s)
    x = liste[0]
    y = liste[1]    
    output.write(str(x) + ',' + str(y))    
    output.write('\n')
    sorted(s, key=lambda x: x[o])
    s = input.readline()
input.close()
output.close()
```

thanks!

Comment: First you say that the code gives the wrong output, then you say it gives an `IndexError`. Which is it? It seems to me that it will actually raise a `NameError` because `o` is not assigned.

Comment: What do you mean by "transforming the decimals", I don't understand what you want to do here. Can you give some examples?

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker: by changing the decimals I meant instead of two decimal values xxxx.oo I would like the code to change them to one decimal values xxx.o

Comment: @interjay: sorry, forget the error code, that was from an earlier attempt. I've deleted it from the question. It's giving me y,x values instead of x,y values, and unsorted.

Comment: How? By chopping off the final digit? By rounding?

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker: ideally rounding, but the only way I am acquainted with is by using the symbol % but I am faced with the float issue as explained above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try to format your code according to [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)—it'll be easier to read. (I've done the cleanup in your post already).

Second, Tim is right in that you should try to learn how to write your code as (idiomatic) Python not just as if translated directly from its C equivalent.

As a starting point, I'll post your 2nd snippet here, refactored as idiomatic Python:

```
# there is no need to import the `string` module; `.strip()` is a built-in
# method of strings (i.e. objects of type `str`).

# read in the data as a list of pairs of raw (i.e. unparsed) coordinates in
# string form:
with open(r'C:\coordinates.txt') as in_file:
    coords_raw = [line.strip().split() for line in in_file.readlines()]

# convert the raw list into a list of pairs (2-tuples) containing the parsed
# (i.e. float not string) data:
coord_pairs = [(float(x_raw), float(y_raw)) for x_raw, y_raw in coords_raw]

coord_pairs.sort()  # you want to sort the entire data set, not just values on
                    # individual lines as in your original snippet

# build a list of all x and y values we have (this could be done in one line
# using some `zip()` hackery, but I'd like to keep it readable (for you at
# least)):
all_xs = [x for x, y in coord_pairs]
all_ys = [y for x, y in coord_pairs]
# compute min and max:
x_min, x_max = min(all_xs), max(all_xs)
y_min, y_max = min(all_ys), max(all_ys)

# NOTE: the above section performs well for small data sets; for large ones, you
# should combine the 4 lines in a single for loop so as to NOT have to read
# everything to memory and iterate over the data 6 times.

# write everything out
with open(r'C:\coordinates_sorted.txt', 'wb') as out_file:
    # here, we're doing 3 things in one line:
    #   * iterate over all coordinate pairs and convert the pairs to the string
    #     form
    #   * join the string forms with a newline character
    #   * write the result of the join+iterate expression to the file
    out_file.write('\n'.join('%f,%f' % (x, y) for x, y in coord_pairs))

    out_file.write('\n\n')
    out_file.write('%f %f %f %f' % (x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max))
```

`with open(...) as <var_name>` gives you guaranteed closing of the file handle as with `try-finally`; also, it's shorter than `open(...)` and `.close()` on separate lines. Also, `with` can be used for other purposes, but is commonly used for dealing with files. I suggest you look up how to use `try-finally` as well as `with`/context managers in Python, in addition to everything else you might have learned here.

Comment: Hi Erik. Many thanks for going through it step by step. Much appreciated as 1) it works (all I had to add was the desired decimal length at the end) and 2) I learnt something.
The reason it may look like C language is that this was the way I was taught by my instructor (I don't know C language at all; Python is my first attempt at programming, thus my lack of skills). 
You and Tim are both right about having to use more idiomatic coding but hopefully that will come with time and the more I read about it in manuals/tutorials and try exercises like this.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks more like C than like Python; it is quite unidiomatic. I suggest you read the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html) to find some inspiration. For example, iterating using a `while` loop is usually the wrong approach. The `string` module is deprecated for the most part, `<>` should be `!=`, you don't need to call `str()` on an object that's already a string...

Then, there are some errors. For example, `sorted()` returns a sorted version of the iterable you're passing - you need to assign that to something, or the result will be discarded. But you're calling it on a string, anyway, which won't give you the desired result. You also wrote `x[o]` where you clearly meant `x[0]`.

You should be using something like this (assuming Python 2):

```
with open(r'C:\coordinates.txt') as infile:
    values = []
    for line in infile:
        values.append(map(float, line.split()))
values.sort()
with open(r'C:\coordinates_sorted.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for value in values:
        outfile.write("{:.1f},{:.1f}\n".format(*value))
```